# sequelize nodejs return the data that are supposed to show up at the current time

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have Product Model That Have Two Columns `startDate` and `duration`

The `startDate` it's the datetime are products supposed to show up

And `duration` is the showing time per day,

This is the code I have written

```
const dateTimeNow = new Date() 
    const productData = await productModel.findAll({
            where: {
               startDate: { [Op.gte]: dateTimeNow }, // StartDate >= dateTimeNow
            },
```

what I want Is :
find all products where startDate >= date.now() & startDate + duration <= date.now()

how can I do that in sequelize?

Answer (score 0):

From the Sequelize doc, you can use

```
const Op = Sequelize.Op;

// startDate and endDate are Date objects
const where = {
    startDate: {
        [Op.between]: [startDate, endDate]
    }
};
```

NOTE: `between` is inclusive that means (startDate <= from AND from <= endDate)

Learn more on operators in the doc http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/#operators

Comment: what I want Is : find all products where startDate >= date.now() & startDate + duration <= date.now()

Comment: so you just need to define or replace endDate as startDate + duration make sure you do it properly with a helper library like moment or date fns